# Generate routes using client address

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

We have an angular page that accesses a restful web service we are also generating. For the website we are making the routes match those of the web service for simplicity. For example accessing the website at http://myserver.com/books/book/1/chapter/2 would access the same route in the web service.

Now the slightly tricky part, if a list of books was returned then each book would contain a link to itself.

```
"links": [
    {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://myserver.com/books/book/1"
    }]
```

The problem is in web api we use Url.Link to generate the href value. This though gives the server address as the web service and not the requesting angular website. We want to use these references to auto generate links on the web page itself. But they obviously just link straight back to the web service.

Generated: http://myWebServiceServer.com/books/book/1
Ideal: http://myWebSiteServer.com/books/book/1

Is there any nice function like Url.Link that the correct server could be specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote Scott Allen, "technically, you shouldn't use the Url property in an api controller to generate non-webapi links".  I'm no expert on producing restful webapi's but it doesn't seem like a good design if the routing of the returned url is dependant on the routing of the calling website.  Shouldn't the api just return information regarding books etc and let the website construct its own urls based on that information.

Regardless, the Url.Link you stated that you are using always returns an absolute url (i.e. http://myWebServiceServer.com/books/book/1).

If you insist on returning a url you could use Url.Route which can produce a relative url (i.e. /books/book/1).  Your calling website can then determine the server to be added to the url.

Comment: Yes the discussion in the office did eventually reach the same conclusion. having the web service know about clients is a definite non starter. Relative paths seem to provide enough information.